# Approach to create team roster?

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I'm trying to create a team roster content type. Each team member has first name, last name, tel number, character name and a photo.

Attempt #1:
 I've installed NameField module which allowed me to add/edit players on the team. The problem with Name field is that i can create unlimited number of players in team roster, but namefield doesn't provide a field to upload a photo to each of them.

Attempt #2:
I tried to create a content type called 'Player' with fields for name, photo, and tel number. Then create a View with sorted table. My problem: User needs to constantly click add Player to create more than one player. Is there any way to make it more user-friendly?  For example,
Just click 'Add one more field' without getting into content creating menu?

Question: 
Approach to create sorted table view of players name, tel. number, and photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

Create a collection of fields and then attach it to the content type as one field.

Comment: That worked well!